How to get output as dbf from a pandas dataframe?
I am a beginner in python. I have a csv file, in which I need to do some modification and then get the output as dbf file. (which can be opened in foxpro). Can somebody guide? I want to get this dph1 dataframe into dbf. I did some searching and found that pysal might do the trick. But how?
import pandas as pd
dph1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Souvik\Downloads\ADEE.csv")
dph1 = dph1.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
dph1.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
dph1.sort_values(by=['dsl'], inplace=True)


Export to CSV then use the linked approach to convert from CSV to DBF
